# Bing 8 event handler not working correctly

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have the following code snippet:

```js
function hello()
{
  alert("hello");
}

//in my map initialization code
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(myPin, 'click', function(e){ $('#box').click();});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="hello()" id="box">
```

Now when I click on the push pin on the map, I see the checkbox check/uncheck meaning the click is working. However, the **onclick** of the checkbox is never triggered. This was working fine in bing 7 but not bing 8. Any ideas what could be causing this odd behavior?

changing the push pin event type to **mouseover** or **mouseout** works fine, but **click** or **mouseup** or **mousedown** don't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that cropped up recently. If you add your pushpin to a Layer and add the click event to the layer, it will work. For example:

```
var layer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
layer.add(myPin);

Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(layer, 'click', function(e){ $('#box').click();});
```

Alternatively, try the experimental branch to see if this is already fixed. To try the experimental branch, add **&branch=experimental** to the map script URL.

Comment: adding the pushpin to layer and then adding the click event to the layer doesn't work either.